# Python built-in type as function parameter

Tags: python

I've decided to do some coding exercises at coderbyte.com and right in the first exercise (reverse a string) I found this:

```
def FirstReverse(str):
```

Even though it works, I don't think it's a good idea to use a built-in type name as a parameter. What do you think?
I know it's kinda silly, but it's my first question at stackoverflow! Thanks =)

Comment: It's not a great idea, but as long as you're not using `str` inside the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that function definition, `str` is supposed to be a `string`, not the [built-in function `str()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). When you do this, you are overwriting the built-in function, so you *won't be able to call `str()`* inside the function `f`, but you can still using it outside. This is because scoping, you are overwriting it in the local scope of `f`:

```
def f(str):
    print str(123) # will raise an error, because 'str' is not callable (i.e. a function) anymore

f("some string here")

print str(123) # OK
```

This is a very common mistake, the sooner you learn to avoid it, the sooner you will become a good programmer.

Comment: Voted you up. Answer seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: The statement *you won't be able to call str() as a function again* is straight out wrong. You only won't be able to call `str` from inside of `f`. It is a local variable. Not that the use of `str` is endorsed -- only that your answer is wrong -- I down voted it. I will reverse if corrected. :-)

Comment: @dawg Edited. But what did you mean by *"use of `str` is endorsed"*? I'm not a English native speaker and I couldn't find an appropriate translation of "endorsed".

Comment: I said "**Not** *that the use of str is endorsed*". As in -- don't use `str` as a parameter name in a function...  Downvote reversed...

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use "anything" except keywords as variable/parameter names.

It's usually not a good idea though - as in practically never.

---

Perhaps the example is from Python1 series where there was a string module, but no `str` type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the one that voted Christian's answer down but here's an elaboration if it helps:

#### Working Function

```
def f(string):
    print ("In function.")
    print (string)
    print (type(string))
    real_string = str(string)
    print (type(real_string))

print ("In main.")
int_val = 123
print (type(int_val))
f(int_val)
```

#### Results

In main.
In function.
123
class 'int'
class 'str'

#### Broken Function

```
def f(str):
    print ("In function.")
    print (str)
    print (type(str))
    real_string = str(str)
    print (type(real_string))

print ("In main.")
int_val = 123
print (type(int_val))
f(int_val)
```

#### Results

----> 5     real_string = str(str)
  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

The use of `list`, `dict`, `str` as variable names is a common newby 'mistake'.

I think that it is not a good practice for tutorials, but works OK in practice *in this example*. I would frown if code was presented to me with that parameters name however.

The more interesting thing to explore is WHY doesn't this tramp on the built-in `str` function.

Look:

```
>>> str(123)        # the built-in prior to the function 'f' declared
'123'
>>> def f(str):     # Note 'str' as parameter
...    return str[::-1]
... 
>>> f('123')        # function works...
'321'
>>> f(str(123))     # function 'f' works with the function 'str' prior
'321'
>>> str(123)        # built-in 'str' still works...
'123'
```

The answer is that in `f` the `str` parameter overrides the built-in `str` function only locally -- inside of `f`. It is 'restored' to the built-in `str` after the scope of `f` is done.

Notice:

```
>>> def f(str):
...    return str('123')[::-1]
... 
>>> f(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Since you are calling `int` inside `f` you are referring to the parameter, not the function. It gets confusing and, hence, not a great idea to use the name of a built-in as a variable, parameter, etc whether local or global.